# The requested URL / was not found on this server. Flask in apache server

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi, apache2.4

Iam following this link "https://medium.com/@madumalt/flask-app-deployment-in-windows-apache-server-mod-wsgi-82e1cfeeb2ed" to deploy flask app in windows........

1)**Usually this was in my http-vhosts.conf file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**and now below that I added server name, WSGIScriptAlias, directory to it so that it look like this:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/Tirumalesh/dev/text_basic/web.wsgi"    
    DocumentRoot "D:/Tirumalesh/dev/text_basic"   
    <Directory D:/Tirumalesh/dev/text_basic>                        
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2) **and I have added (below 3 lines) in my httpd.conf(in the very end of file) which is the output coming from "mod_wsgi-express module-config" and I have included "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" (virtual hosts) in my httpd.conf file**

```
LoadFile "c:/users/lucid/anaconda3/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/lucid/anaconda3/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/lucid/anaconda3"
```

3)**Next i create a web.wsgi file with the following content**

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'D:\Tirumalesh\dev\text_basic')
from text_basic import app as application

4)And my python file is "text_basic.py" (whose name must be same as my .wsgi file)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return ("Hello World qwertyuiop!!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

After that i restarted my apache server and tried running "localhost" but im not getting "Hello World qwertyuiop!!" this output in my html page instead im getting **"The requested URL / was not found on this server."**

Is there anything i missed in this??

**NOTE**: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases/download/4.4.12/mod_wsgi-windows-4.4.12.tar.gz

Instead of downloading this "mod_wsgi-windows-4.4.12.tar.gz" this file and looking for the right mod_wsgi.so file and copy it to my  "C:\Users\lucid\VS16\Apache24\modules" and pasting **.so** file,
 I downloaded mod_wsgi using "pip install mod_wsgi"and after i ran "mod_wsgi-express module-config" and copied the below output to httpd.conf at last line of the file.......

```
LoadFile "c:/users/lucid/anaconda3/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/lucid/anaconda3/lib/sitepackages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37- 
   win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/lucid/anaconda3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using python3 (3.7) and you're using pip.
Instead of using `pip install mod_wsgi`, go with `pip3 install mod_wsgi` and enable the debug mode (temporarily for debugging purpose).